# Count occurrences in specific columns using array formula google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in Google Sheets, Let's say the named sheet is *Sheet 1*. In *Sheet 1*, I have data in the range `'Sheet 1'!A:E` as pictured below:

[image]

In column F, i would like to count the occurrences in columns A, D and E for each row independently and place the count in column F for each respective row.

Below is an example of my expected output based on the sample data above.

[image]

Before that, i have created formula using array formula but it not worked. Following my formula in column F:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(COUNTIF(A2:A<>""; TRUE); COUNTIF(D2:D<>""; TRUE); COUNTIF(E2:E<>""; TRUE)))
```

Please advise me how I can fix the formula to correct this sheet. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_F2`:*

```js
=byrow(hstack(A2:A;D2:D;E2:E);lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;counta(Σ))))
```

Comment: **remove the if-condition part `if(counta(Σ)=0;;` if you wish for count `0` to be visible as well